# Acceder a un objeto con llave en string dentro de un Objeto

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objeto

Estoy intentando acceder al "offical-artwork" dentro del objeto `pokemon.sprites.other`, hasta donde se para poder acceder debería de ser `pokemon.sprites.other.offical-artwork`, pero me lanza que este no esta definido y al llamar este hasta others me muestra lo siguiente en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se logra observar que el objeto cuenta con otro objeto que se llama **"official-artwork"** lo que no comprendo es porque este se encuentra con comillas y los otros objetos como ***dream_world*** y ***home*** se encuentran si comillas, entiendo que este debe ser el problema pero no tengo idea de como acceder a el, ya que si utilizo los objetos anteriormente mencionados se logra acceder sin ningún inconveniente, de antemano gracias por la ayuda..!

Comment: ¿Has probado así?  `pokemon.sprites.other.["official-artwork"]`  (por cierto, ahora que lo veo, tu has puesto `pokemon.sprites.other.offical-artwork` y allí te faltaba una `i`... que no sea eso el problema)

Comment: `official-artworkd` no es nombre valido para un objeto ya que contiene el guion (`-`). Asi que deberias acceder a esa propiedad usando corchetes `['official-artwork']` como dice @masterguru

Comment: Gracias exactamente así funciono, la verdad nunca me había topado con este tipo de problemas XD estaba tan sencillo y no se me pudo ocurrir..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como dice @Isaac en los comentarios

> official-artworkd no es nombre valido para un objeto ya que contiene
> el guion (-)

Y también se comenta esto en su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects):

> Sin embargo, cualquier nombre de propiedad que no sea un identificador
> válido de JavaScript (por ejemplo, el nombre de alguna propiedad que
> tenga un espacio o un guión, o comience con un número) solo se puede
> acceder utilizando la notación de corchetes.

Por lo tanto podemos usar la [notación de corchetes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#notaci%C3%B3n_de_corchetes) siguiente para acceder a esa propiedad:

```javascript
pokemon.sprites.other.["official-artwork"]
```

Y según dice el OP le ha funcionado bien.